# Save 2 different PFObjects eventually or fail both

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using Parse SDK for iOS, I have 2 tables :

```
Game
- UserA : Pointer <_User>
- UserB : Pointer <_User>
- Round : Number
- IsTurnOfUserA : Bool

RoundScore
- GameId : Pointer <Game>
- User   : Pointer <_User>
- Score  : Number
- etc
```

A game is done in 3 rounds between 2 users.

When a user ends a round, it toggles `Game.IsTurnOfUserA` and saves the score for the round to `RoundScore` table.

In iOS, I didn't find a way to update Game table AND save a RoundScore **eventually** (maybe later if there is no network).

Both must be done or none at all, but I don't want to end up with only one of the 2 query to be successful and the other one failed.

With Cloud Code, it should be easy to do so but there is no call **eventually** function.

**Update**: Maybe there is something to try with Parse's local database ? But I don't know that tool yet.

**Important**: RoundScore has a field that depends on Game. If Game Object is new, it doesn't have an ObjectId yet, but I still need to link it to the RoundScore Object.

Comment: What if you use block for this purpose ?

Comment: Did you try doing these calls systematically inside a block? As in update one and then in its block save the other eventually. That way they won't conflict.

Comment: The problem of cascading them with callback blocks is that the **eventually** block can be lost if the user quits the app. That means if the first table is saved then the user quits the app, the second table will never be saved. And I have to avoid this kind of scenarios at all cost (therefore both succeed or both fail).

Comment: Why not saveEventually on device as opposed to Cloud Code?

Comment: @soulshined According to the docs, saveEventually only works on a single PFObject and if I apply saveEventually on both objects, there is a possibly that one of them fail. (as stated in previous comment)

Comment: @BabyAzerty we wrote our comments simultaneously so I didn't see it. You are right, Cloud Code doesn't have a save eventually function so you might have to resort to plist or NSUserDefaults for a temp store, which could be the better option considering API request limits, games are popular in the App Store, so if you have thousands of users you utilize two API requests [1 for the query and 1 for save] which will quickly add up.

Comment: Hmmm, is there no way with the local database and pin functions ? I'm not familiar with those yet.

Comment: @BabyAzerty yes, you can pin and unpin objects at any time. They still use API requests, so theres no way around that. Give me a sec i'll provide an answer

Comment: @BabyAzerty actually, I don't have time i have to go to work : here is a resource to use : http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/ it gives you the run down if you don't have an answer that specifically address your original question, or local datastore pinning and unpinning when I get off work i'll provide an answer

Comment: I tried going with the local database but I have a problem when Game object is newly created on the device : even if I `saveEventually`, it doesn't automatically assign an objectId to it. And I need the id of the Game Object for the RoundScore Object (there is a relation column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Timothy Walters suggested, here is the ***hack*** without any background job:

I created a fake table that has the columns of both tables `Game` and `RoundScore`

```
GameAndRoundScore
- Game_UserA
- Game_UserB
- RoundScore_GameId
- RoundScore_Score
- etc
```

In Cloud Code, I added this function before save

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("GameAndScoreRound", function(request, response) {
    var Game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
    var game = new Game();
    game.set("UserA", request.object.get("game_UserA"));
    game.set("UserB", request.object.get("game_UserB"));
    game.save.then(function(newGame) {
        var RoundScore = Parse.Object.extend("RoundScore");
        var roundScore = new RoundScore();
        //roundScore.set(...)
        return scoreRound.save();
    }).then(function(newRoundScore) {
        response.success();
    });
});
```

Then for the fake table data, I can either leave it as it is or set a background job that empties it or even empty the table manually on the Parse Backend.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it isn't possible with `saveEventually`.

What you would need to do is implement your own network checking code and call a cloud method that will save both. That would be the best option.

A hack you could try as an alternative is to save the combined data to another class and have a background job on the server turn that single temporary row into a row in each table, then remove the temporary row.

The drawbacks of this hack is that the background job can run every 15 minutes only, so there might be up-to 15 minutes delay. It also adds extra complexity and overhead to your app.